# How to get the value? To get the date selected in calendar by php after submit the form

Tags: php

Here is the code for calendar on one page. I want to show the value of calendar on next page when user clicks on submit button and move on next page.

```
<td>
    <div data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-   date="document.write(date())" class="input-append date myDatepicker">
        <input  type="text" value="" name="doj" size="16" class="span2" required>
        <span class="add- on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but you could add your value in a hidden form field.

Comment: i want to show the value of calendar on next page means when user select value of calendar on one page it automatically display on next page

Comment: here is a sample of site(http://www.renganathan.in/)when user select departure and arrival on click on search button it display selected value of calendar on next page

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you store your date in a parameter called date.
Link to the place you want it to go like:

```
<a href=\"Projectname/classname?myparam=" +  date + "\"  >
```

In the other class just simply request this param by: 
request.getParameter("myparam");